# UICollectionView cellForRow Crash

Tags: nsindexpath, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello I am having trouble getting a custom object at the index path of the UICollectionView...
Below is my code.

I am getting the crash

[Player firstName:]: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Any suggestions?

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
BenchCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, 120, 50)];


    Player*homeBenchPlayer = [[self homeBench]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.playerName.text = homeBenchPlayer.firstName;
    cell.playerPosition .text = homeBenchPlayer.position;
    cell.playerPicture.image = [ UIImage imageWithData:homeBenchPlayer.picture];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: You are not getting a Player class object from your homebench array...

Comment: Yes I am, I po'ed the object and it is indeed a player class object.

Comment: At which line does the crash occur?

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error unexpectedly I usually return to IB, select the object responsible for the crash, and investigate the Connections Inspector. Generally the problem seems to be an incorrect referencing outlet or sent event.

This could be caused by calling `performSelector:@selector(dismissModal:)` where the callee doesn't exist.